# How to get exact output?

Tags: python

I wrote a program to get words from user and get plural of those words as output. Now I couldn't do following two things

1 - How to restrict only string input i.e if user input integer then program must throw error.

2 - Input - cat mat bat  output-> cats mats bats
    input - cat, mat, bat output -> cat,s mat,s bat,s ( I want to avoid this i.e when user separates the words by comma then i should get bats not bat,s)

please guide me here and please watch out for indentation.

Thank you

```
`(def plural(user_input):
    # creating list 
    List_of_word_ends = ['o','ch', 's', 'sh', 'x', 'z']
    words = user_input.split()
    ws = "";
    # setting loop to for words
    for word in words:
        if len(word)>0 :
            if word.endswith("y"):
                word = word[:-1]
                word += "ies"
            else:
                isSomeEs = False;
                for suffix in List_of_word_ends:
                    if word.endswith(suffix):
                        word += "es"
                        isSomeEs = True;
                        break
                if not isSomeEs:
                    word += "s"
            ws += word+" "
    print ws
# taking input from user
singular = raw_input("Please enter the words whose plural you want:")
# returns a list of words
x = singular.split(" ")
x = singular.split(",")
#calculate the length of object 
y = len(x)
print "The no. of words you entered is :", y 
#function call
plural(singular))`
```

Comment: Your question is currently "my program has bugs and lacks features; please finish it for me," which is 1) not a single question, and 2) not actually a question and thus not on-topic for SO.

Comment: There are parts of this that seem salvageable to me, though not the whole thing. Do some searching for Question 1 and make a good stab at it and I bet we can help you out (maybe post a new question after reading the help center). Question 2 is not tractable through any means in scope of this site - the english language it too complicated for a general-purpose pluralizer that fits in an SO answer

Comment: The second part of your question sounds like you are asking us to write code for you. [We are not your personal programming army!](http://www.quickmeme.com/img/4b/4b3d80c40948899c425bc6e1c3855d83fe4fcacdc5cac049fa9a70a2bc97da4e.jpg) I have posted an answer to help you with the first question, which is somewhat on-topic, if easily googleable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your 1st question

```
# taking input from user
singular = raw_input("Please enter the words whose plural you want:")

try:
   val = int(singular)
except ValueError:
   print("Please enter a valid string. Integer not accepted!!!")
```

Comment: Regarding you 2nd question:

Please enter the words whose plural you want: cat,mat,bat 

Enter the words without any spaces between them. The split() functionality used in your function splits based on the spaces, so dont give any spaces.


Please enter the words whose plural you want:cat,mat,bat
The no. of words you entered is : 3

cat,mat,bats

Mark it as answered if you are satisified with the answer

Answer (score 0):

To help you with your first problem, the problem of input type, add a `try/catch` whenever you have user input. Something like this should work:

```
singular = raw_input("Please enter the words whose plural you want. ")
try:
    int(singular)
except ValueError:
    print "Invalid input! Please try again."
```

Answer (score -1):

Regarding the first requirement - you can do something simple like:

if singular==type(5):
    print 'error'

The 5 in type - can be replace by any int.

Regarding the second requirement - not sure what exactly you are looking for... if you could you please provide an example.

Comment: `singular` will always be a string, if it's a string that represents an integer it still won't be an integer, and it definitely won't be a type. This is all wrong. Also, answers are not the place for questions or clarification - use a comment instead.